# Creating simple Android + GAE Hello world project

Tags: android, xml, google-app-engine, http-post

I have been looking for a tutorial all over the place about a hello world application relating Android and Google App Engine, and I did find some, but they all included the option "app engine connected android project" which is no longer available in Eclipse, as I understand.

Can someone give me links to a good Hello World tutorial combining Android and GAE? Why was the option "app engine connected android project" removed?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (18/9/2013): Seems like it's now available here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

I, too am looking for a tutorial to that. I will update this answer as soon as I know. (EDIT: The closest thing I have for a tutorial is [this](http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/) presented at Google I/O 2011.

The option is removed because, apparently, Google is looking to deploy Google Cloud Endpoints (http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/) as a replacement and the old option was using C2DM which has been deprecated in favour of Google Cloud Messaging (http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html). I've read from some other answers here that Google is looking to reintroduce it into the Eclipse plugin at a later time. Who knows when that will be.

Comment: thanks a lot for the feedback! So I guess I should wait as well and see what happens